# TFSBuild: Fail to build notification

Tags: workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

Okay, is there way to notify user when any build fail?

I want to email the specific user when there is an error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

If you install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) you can use the Alerts Explorer feature, you right click the top level collection, go to Alerts Explorer and add your rules.

You can simply select New Alert > Build Alerts > Failed Builds, change the `Requested for` value and add a `Status Code` with a Value of `Failed` (or whatever you want), change the `Send To:` (this also accepts multiple values in case you want team leaders to get notifications etc).

I don't know if there is any way to configure this so each individual user gets their own alerts configured, you could always setup alerts in an admin account, but would mean doing it once for every person that needs notifications... Not ideal I know!  However if you really want to be hot on those build failures...

The other option is the Team Foundation Build Notification tool, but I don't really trust this as it seems to have "issues" with showing updates, although the toast popup notifications seems to work well.